# Why does sed /^$/d delete only blank lines but /^$/p print all lines?

Tags: regex, sed

I'm able to use `sed /^$/d <file>` to delete all the blank lines in the file, but what if I want to print all the blank lines only?  The command `sed /^$/p <file>` prints all the lines in file.

The reason I want to do this is that we use an EDA program (Expedition) that uses regex to run rules on the names of nets.  I'm trying to find a way to search for all nets that don't have names assigned.  I thought using `^$` would work, but it just ends up finding all nets, which is what `/^$/p` is doing too.  So is there a different way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unless otherwise specified [**sed**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) will print the pattern space when it has finished processing it. If you look carefully at your output you'll notice that you get 2 blank lines for every one in the file.  You'll have to use the -n command line switch to stop sed from printing.

```
sed -n /^$/p infile
```

Should work as you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `grep` as:

```
grep '^$' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

Sed prints every line by default, and so the p flag is useless.  To make it useful, you need to give sed the -n switch.  Indeed, the following appears to do what you want:

```
sed -n /^$/p
```

Answer (score 1):

think in another way, don't **p**, but **!d**

you may try:

```
sed '/^$/!d' yourFile
```